# Avoiding double click action in title of field name (DataGrid)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In VB.NET (VS2008 .NET Framework 2.0) I want to launch an event when double clicking any row of a DataGridView. I got this using the event CellContentDoubleClick, but the problem is when I do double click in the titles of DataGridView the event launches too. I just want to avoid actions in the titles.

How could I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [CellContentDoubleClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentdoubleclick%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event you can check if you click on column/row header using this code:

```
If e.ColumnIndex = -1 Or e.RowIndex = -1 Then
    'do what you want (maybe Exit Sub)
End If
```

If you need to stop only column header double click remove any reference to `e.RowIndex`.